# Access Denied error calling AWS Pinpoint API from EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I'm trying to send an SMS message from an EKS pod using the Java SDK. I've created a role with policy (shown below), associated that role with a ServiceAccount, and associated the ServiceAccount with my deployment. When I call the SendTextMessage API, I receive the following:

> software.amazon.awssdk.services.pinpointsmsvoicev2.model.AccessDeniedException:
> User:
> arn:aws:sts:::assumed-role/auth-dev-serviceaccount-role/aws-sdk-java-1703174127711 is not authorized to perform: sms-voice:SendTextMessage because no
> identity-based policy allows the sms-voice:SendTextMessage action
> (Service: PinpointSmsVoiceV2, Status Code: 400, Request ID:
> 569fc680-4d9c-4ad3-a5be-fa0a5b4d62ad)

The policy associated with auth-dev-serviceaccount-role is:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "sms-voice:*",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnLike": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sms-voice:*:<account_id>:*"
                },
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceAccount": "<account_id>"
                }
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Sid": "SMSVoiceFullAccess"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Trust relationship looks like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::<account id>:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/id/9E19C2D11165947D17A2934157497968"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
        }
    ]
}
```

The spec for the Deployment shows that the service account is associated:

> serviceAccountName: auth-dev-serviceaccount
> serviceAccount: auth-dev-serviceaccount

and the error message indicates that the correct role (auth-dev-serviceaccount-role) was assumed.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK. it looks like the 2 conditional clauses in the policy were to blame. When I removed them, everything worked fine. Not sure I needed those clauses in the first place.

And from Amazon re:Post I learned:

> On inspecting the policy I observed that you added the below
> “Condition” element to “sms-voice:*” on all for resources. But
> Pinpoint SMS Voice has no service-specific context keys that can be
> used in the Condition element of policy statements.
>
> Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon Pinpoint SMS and
> Voice Service - Condition keys for Amazon Pinpoint SMS and Voice
> Service -
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonpinpointsmsandvoiceservice.html#amazonpinpointsmsandvoiceservice-policy-keys